# why does rewriterule not work in apache glassfish jsf combination

Tags: jsf, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I must admit I'm have little experience doing frontend development and infrastructure.

In a jsf2.3 webapp I try to create a nice looking URL.

https://fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl/ventoux/deelnemer.xhtml?id=1

This one shows nicely the page of 1 person.
I want https://fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl/ventoux/fietser/1 to show the same page. However it delivers a page 404.

My testservers apache configuration is as follows for this domain:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Directory /var/www/html/fiersenvoorgaandeweg>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            require all granted
    </Directory>
    ServerName "fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl"
    ServerAlias "www.fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl"
    ServerAdmin info@myserver.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fiersenvoorgaandeweg
    ErrorLog /var/log/fiersenvoorgaandeweg.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/fiersenvoorgaandeweg.custom.log combined
    SSLEngine On
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule     ^ventoux/fietser/([^/]+)/?$ ventoux/deelnemer.xhtml?id=$1 [L]
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl/fiersenvoorgaandeweg.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl/chain.crt
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        /vent          http://localhost/
    ProxyPassReverse /vent          http://localhost/
    ProxyPass        /              http://localhost:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse /              http://localhost:9090/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Somway I oversee something. Can anybody tell me what?

Comment: https://fiersenvoorgaandeweg.nl/ventoux/fietser/1 works for me... no 404 here. Succes met de inzameling!

Comment: Thank you, I redirected the 404 error to the home page.so you don't see it as 404 error. As you can see the other url with deelnemer.xhtml?id=1 results into another page and that's the preferred result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement pretty-faces to implement the desired url. Quit simple.

```
<url-mapping id="biker">
    <pattern value="/fietser/#{id}" />
    <view-id value="/deelnemer.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

However, I did some extra's to beautify the url:

in my ear I created an application.xml file with an empty contextPath so the war name never comes up in the url.
I changed the ugly faces prefix by *.xhtml.

Now https://sitename/fietser/1 shows the biker just as I meant to.